# removing of array elements an issue

Tags: javascript

I have a situation where i add tables on a click of button and each table is stored in array. Now when i remove 2 or 3 tables, wrong index are being removed.

```
addTable: function (obj) {
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {

        // Adding of table
        array.push(obj)
        // delete code of the table 
        (function (i) {
            deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                array.splice(i, 1);

            });
        })(i);

    }
}
```

The problem i am facing is the value of i is always `zero`. each time i click on the button a the `addTable` function is called and the counter is always `zero` and that is passed to the `function(i)` too.

Any ideas on how can keep track of different i or counter so that it deletes the correct index in the array

**Here is an update**

this is the sample object i am sending each time.

Each time i click on the Add Table button, the same object is being passed. Now i am having difficulty in keeping track of the index of each item.

Comment: how do you call the addTable function? i depends on obj which is passed into the function so there is not enough information to answer your question.

Comment: What is `obj` ? and what is `obj[i]` ? what is `deleteButton` ?

Comment: @John Cooper: You dont answer about `deleteButton`. It's a one button in page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've removed one table, all other tables have moved and their indexes that you installed in the delete Buttons will be wrong now.  When you remove items from the array, all indexes shift.

So, suppose you remove table 3.  Then, you press delete for table 4.  It's got an index of 4, but since you already removed table 3, it's in spot 3 in the array now (after the previous delete), not spot 4.  But, you're code still has i==4 associated with that table and is trying to delete it here, but it's not there any more.

What you are doing is just not a good way to do this.  If you want to expand further on what you're really trying to do, we can help with much better solutions.

Given the limited info we have so far, all I know of to do is to find the item in the array (wherever it might have moved to) and delete it from there.

```
addTable: function (obj) {
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {

        // Adding of table
        array.push(obj)
        // delete code of the table 
        (function (item) {
            deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                // search through the array to find where this item is 
                // and remove it from the array
                for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
                    if (array[j] === item) {
                        array.splice(j, 1);   // remove it
                        break;
                    }
                }

            });
        })(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right about indexes, but in Q.: adding and removing tables, not table rows.

Comment: @AndrewD - OK, changed the terminology in my description to be tables, not rows.  No difference in the code or issue.

Comment: @JohnCooper - why is obj the same for every single table?  If so, why put N copies of the same object in an array.  It makes no sense to me.  Either get rid of the array (and thus not have this problem) or make each object different in which case my code will work fine.

Comment: @jfriend00: the table is getting created based on the object... i have four keys and four rows are created in the table...

Comment: @jfriend00: how to make each object different.... the objects key and value creates the rows...

Comment: Indexes in an array shift as you remove items.  You can't "store" the index for a particular table object.  You will have to do some sort of lookup if you want to find it.  There are lots of ways to make a lookup table, but we'd need to know more about what problem you're really trying to solve to know what to suggest.

Comment: @JohnCooper - why are you storing those objects in an array if they are all the same?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3846/discussion-between-jfriend00-and-john-cooper)

Answer (score 1):

if `obj.length` is undefined `i` will allways be `0`

further more, then `i < obj.length` return `false` and the `for` loop will never execute

if `obj` passed in is this object:

```
var addObjectResponse = [{...}];
```

then `addObjectResponse` is an array of 1, hence `i` will allways be 0

```
i = 0
obj.length = 1
```

`i < obj.length` => `0 < 1` => true once

Comment: If `obj.length` is undefined, then `for` loop is never executed.

Comment: He sad i is zero in the `function(i)` call so the for loop is executed and obj.lenght can not be undefinded.

Comment: true, which doesn't change the fact that we need to know more about obj to answer

Answer (score 1):

I do not know about `deleteButton`, but in case that `obj` is array with only one element (`length` equals 1): `[{....}]` and `array.push` is native `Array.prototype.push` method  then:

```
addTable: function (obj) {
  // Adding of table
  var index=array.push(obj);
  // delete code of the table 
  deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function (e) { array.splice(index, 1); });
}
```